# Proactively telling the interviewer about other interviews

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, leadership, competition

Applying and interviewing for leadership positions in Australia!

**Context**:

OK, there is a Company X that I interviewed with recently and I really want to work for them. The interview was very very positive for me and them and I could sense they are keen to progress me to the next stage. They said they will get back to me by Friday this week.

However, the general manager of Company Y which I interviewed with recently invited me to visit the office again on Friday to meet the team and subsequently "have a chat" with him. I feel this is going to be an offer negotiation "chat."

**Challenge**:

Company X is my first preference and I'm afraid that if they get back to me, say on Wednesday, to invite me for the next stage interview on mid next week, I will have given an answer to the offer from Company Y.

**Question**:

Should I somehow let company X know about my upcoming "interview" with company Y, so they may speed things up a bit? If so, what would the best way to go about this? Or just let it be as if nothing is happening.

Comment: They are not going to shortcut you through the interview stages because of your personal situation, unless you are an amazing candidate. They probably have multiple candidates to proceed through the different processes. If Company X was my dream job, I'd try to postpone the meeting with Y as much as possible.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie: Although short, this could be an answer

Comment: Even if Company Y does present you with an offer on Friday, what prevents you from replying with "Thank you very much for the offer - I will consider it over the weekend and get back to you by [some day] next week"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not going to shortcut you through the interview stages because of your personal situation, unless you are an amazing candidate. They probably have multiple candidates to proceed through the different processes.

If Company X was my dream job, I'd try to postpone the meeting with Y as much as possible.

Comment: Absolutely not true.  While they won't skip steps, its incredibly normal to hear someone haas a pending offer and move up the schedule, arranging for interviews to happen in rapid succession.  This happens literally all the time.  Like every interview loop I've don e myself for the past 15 years, and many of the ones I sit in for.  One of the first things HR does is ask me what my interview schedule is like to make things work with it-  has been everywhere I've interviews in the last decade.

Comment: I'm a hiring manager and this is not true at all. If a strong candidate tells me they have other interviews lined up, we will do everything in our power to expedite the process and get an offer in their hands.

Comment: @HelpfulFriend And the other candidates?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie This probably varies by company and situation but we don’t necessarily hire for a set number of open roles, or have multiple candidates interviewing at once unless it’s for a specialized role. Instead we are always passively recruiting and will add talent to the team when we come across it.